# Query a date in MongoDB when it's stored as plain-text and format YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date, mongoskin

I am building a "filtering" system and I need to query users in the collection whose date of birth dates are between 2 dates.

The code I have right now looks like:

```
if (req.query.ageMin) {
  var dobMin = new Date(dateNow.setFullYear(dateNow.getFullYear() - req.query.ageMin));
}
if (req.query.ageMax) {
  var dobMax = dateNow.setFullYear(dateNow.getFullYear() - req.query.ageMax);
}

if (dobMin && dobMax) {
  query.dob = {
    $gte: dobMin,
    $lt: dobMax
  }
} else if (dobMin) {
  query.dob = {
    $gte: dobMin
  }
} else if (dobMax) {
  query.dob = {
    $lt: dobMax
  }
}

db.users.find(query).toArray(function (err, users) {
  console.log(users);
});
```

An empty array is returned (no error).
I assume it's because the date in the collection are not a date object -- they are simply strings for example "1980-06-15".
Is there any option I can pass to the query so that Mongo makes the stored date a date object when querying it? Or any solution for that matter...

Comment: If *dateNow* is a plain JS Date, when you do `dateNow.setFullYear(…)` you are modifying the value of *dateNow*. So if you are looking for someone between 18 and 20 in 2016, then *dobMin* will be 1998 and *dobMax* will be 1978. Also, *setFullYear* returns a time value, not a Date, so *dobMax* is a number whereas *dobMin* is a Date. Though comparisons using comparison operators will still work as they will coerce Dates to number.

Comment: Good catch, actually caught that and added the new Date() function on dobMax as well. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting the date instances to strings:

```
dobMin = dobMin.toISOString().substring(0, 10)
dobMax = dobMax.toISOString().substring(0, 10)
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually solved it similarly by doing `dobMax = dobMax.toISOString().split('T')[0];`

Comment: Note that `new Date(dateNow.setFullYear(dateNow.getFullYear() - req.query.ageMin))` will use the host timezone offset, but *toISOString* uses UTC. Not a problem if the host time zone is +00:00 or greater, but for time zones -00:15 or greater (e.g. all of North and South America), the date will be the day before.